# Is $PATH in WSL supposed to be very long?

Tags: environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Anybody else get an extra long path using `echo $PATH` command? I'm working in BASH shell Ubuntu on windows from the Windows app store.

Output of `echo $PATH`:

```
home/mnhir/bin:/home/mnhir/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Users/hersh/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin
```

Comment: is this your personal machine? or a work/commercial machine?

Comment: also do you have a windows partition mounted?

Comment: personal. fedora 7 Linux bible shows it stops after several bins. why is mine going to /usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: what do you mean? its not a dual boot set up its ubuntu from windows store app terminal only.

Comment: ubuntu uses E:/ and windows uses C:/

Comment: my mistake I somehow managed to read over the ubuntu shell on windows part several times and only read ubuntu shell

Answer (score 12):

It looks like your Windows `%PATH%` has been appended to the Linux `$PATH`. And that is probably the case. See [WSL interoperability with Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop):

> To make Windows executables easier to run, Windows path is included in
> the Linux `$PATH` in Fall Creators Update.

This feature can apparently [be disabled using the Windows registry](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1640#issuecomment-276408942), if it's not needed.

Comment: mainly I am working through this book to secure my network and browse anonymously. plus, I should've spent more on my laptop so im sending this pos back. I hate this laptop compared to my desktop.

Comment: yeah I can dump creators updates. But, why would I want to do that?

Answer (score 10):

In WSL, you can now disable Windows paths getting added to `$PATH` by editing the `/etc/wsl.conf` file. You may need to restart your WSL session for this change to take effect.

An example of its contents would be:

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=false
```

More info can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-per-distro-launch-settings-with-wslconf).